# hidden templates - preventing an angularjs directive from rendering itself

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive that generates html content based on its configuration.  It can be used as an attribute (A) or element (E).  When it is implemented as an element it might look like this:

```
<my-directive setting="dostuff"></my-directive>
```

I do not want the above html node to render in the final output because it affects the visual appearance of the page (it is counted as a node by the css selector ':(first-child)').

I am not using the template attribute because i am manually generating complex html content to be added.   Setting the "replace" attribute to true does not prevent the node from rendering.  I know angular needs a node to hang the directive upon.  I thought i might be able to set the template attribute to a comment ie. "`<!--placeholder-->`" but comments do not seem to be acceptable templates.  So, is it possible to have an empty template?  Suggestions?

Comment: checkout : transclude element